# How to display an info while onDataSetChanged() is runnig in a widget?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-widget

I have a widget which scans for wifi network for about 5 seconds and then displays the results in a `ListView`.

This scan occurs within the `onDataSetChanged()` method.

How can I replace the old data for an information, like "wait...", while the scanning is running?

I have an empty `View` with a text "scanning...", every time the widget is created it works this way.

Comment: please post your widget layout